# firebaseAuth with Angular: User Login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using Angular (1.3.5) and Firebase to write a toy blog program, and am currently struggling with the user login part.

I first created an Angular module:

```
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', ['ngRoute', 'firebase', 'RegistrationController']);
```

Then on top of blogApp, I created a controller called ** RegistrationController **:

```
blogApp.controller('RegistrationController', function ($scope, $firebaseAuth, $location) {

        var ref = new Firebase('https://myAppName.firebaseio.com');
       // var authLogin = $firebaseAuth(ref);


        $scope.login = function(){

            ref.authWithPassword({
                email: $scope.user.email,
                password: $scope.user.password
            }, function(err, authData) {
                if (err) {
                    $scope.message = 'login error';
                } else {
                    $scope.message = 'login sucessful!';
                }
            });
        }; // login

  });  //RegistrationController
```

I attached the `login()` method to ng-submit in my user-login form in the scope of `RegistratinController`.

When I click to submit the login form, the form does not make any response, without any errors showing.

**The login form works only when I click the 'Submit' button twice - why is this? confusing**

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having exact same issue. Answer provided below does not work for me either

Comment: Let me know if my answered work for you. If so please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the Firebase JavaScript library and not AngularFire for the login methods.

You need to pass the Firebase reference into the `$firebaseAuth` binding.

```
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
```

From there you can call `auth.$authWithPassword`.

```
    $scope.login = function(){

        auth.$authWithPassword({
            email: $scope.user.email,
            password: $scope.user.password
        }, function(err, authData) {
            if (err) {
                $scope.message = 'login error';
            } else {
                $scope.message = 'login successful!';
            }
        });
    }; // login
```

AngularFire is an Angular binding for the Firebase Library that handles auto syncing over objects and arrays. AngularFire also handles when to call `$scope.apply` to properly update the view.

In your case, the login code is working the first click, but it doesn't get applied to the page. You can wrap this code in a `$timeout`, but it would be better to use the `$firebaseAuth` service.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you reproduce this in a Plunker? From the code you gave me, the answer is accurate.

Comment: @TonyGW David's answer here is correct. You need to tell Angular the data was updated and trigger a compile. Update your question with new code if you are still having issues or accept his answer for others experiencing similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user **jacobawenger**, for the solution he posted here:

[Can't get new password authentication methods to work in AngularFire 0.9.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084786/cant-get-new-password-authentication-methods-to-work-in-angularfire-0-9-0/27094044#27094044)

This works as expected:

```
myApp.controller('RegistrationController', 
    function($scope, $firebaseAuth, $location) {

    var ref = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com');
    var simpleLogin = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    $scope.login = function() {
        simpleLogin.$authWithPassword({
            email: $scope.user.email,
            password: $scope.user.password
        }).then(function() {
            $location.path('/mypage');
        }, function(err) {
            $scope.message = err.toString();
        });
    } // login

}); // RegistrationController
```